# Redirect stdin and stdout in bash for comprehensive log files

Tags: bash, shell, logging, io-redirection

I am having some troubles creating a comprehensive log file using I/O redirection. What I have is, a bash shell script that creates text files that are later used for input into a few FORTRAN programs. So basically I have;

```
echo -e "Responses \nTo \nFORTRAN \nPromts" > myprogram.in

myprogram < myprogram.in
```

This works fine and I get the results I need from the FORTRAN program, but I would like to have a record (file.log) displaying the FORTRAN prompt (stdout) followed by the response (stdin), then another FORTRAN prompt and response.

So far I have only been able to come up with something like this;

```
echo -e "Responses \nTo \nFORTRAN \nPromts" > myprogram.in

tee file.log < myprogram.in | myprogram >> file.log
```

which produces a file.log like the following example;

*Responses

   To

   FORTRAN

   Prompts*

*This is the opening prompt for myprogram*

*"Please enter something"*
   *You replied "Responses"*

*"Please enter something else"*
   *You replied "To"*

etc...

I understand that basically what I have done is used tee to copy the stdin to the file.log and pipe it into myprogram as well. Then just have redirected the program prompts to the file.log.

Is there anyway possible to redirect the responses and prompts to be redirected to the program simultaneously so the questions and responses are in chronological order in my log file like this;

*This is the opening prompt for myprogram*

*"Please enter something"*
   *Responses*

*You replied "Responses"*

*"Please enter something else"*
   *To*

*You replied "To"*
etc....

Comment: This question seems somewhat straightforward and I thought it could be done easily, but I'm starting to think it is impossible just using I/O redirection ( Such as pipes, file descriptors, process subs, and even tee). The answer may be just to patch the FORTRAN programs to echo the input rather than try to retrieve it using the shell?

Answer (score 1):

You might try the "script" program - it may or may not help depending on how your FORTRAN program addresses the screen. Basically, you run:

```
script somefilename
```

and then run your program as before. When you are done, hit Ctrl-D. All the session is recorded in the file you specified after the word "script".

Or, depending on your terminal, you may be able to type "Ctrl-A" after you have run your program to select all the input and output, and then you may have a menu option to copy it all so you can paste it into a document.

Comment: Thanks you for the response. Unfortunately I have already tried the script command. It does capture the prompts from the FORTRAN program but does not capture the stdin to the FORTRAN program.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you want, but think the following could be made to work, using "expect". First, I simulate your FORTRAN program crudely with some Perl - of course you would use your own real FORTRAN program:

```
Filename: FORTRAN_prog

#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
print "FORTRAN Question 1:";
my $name = <STDIN>;
print "FORTRAN Question 2:";
$name = <STDIN>;
print "FORTRAN Question 3:";
$name = <STDIN>;
for(my $i=0;$i<10;$i++){
print "FORTRAN output $i\n"
}
```

Then I run and control and log it using "expect", like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ./FORTRAN_prog
expect "Question 1:"
send "Answer 1\n"
expect "Question 2:"
send "Answer 2\n"
expect "Question 3:"
send "Answer 3\n"
interact
```

The output looks like this, which I presume you can copy/paste, or capture using the "script" command before running it (see my previous answer).

```
FORTRAN Question 1:Answer 1
FORTRAN Question 2:Answer 2
FORTRAN Question 3:Answer 3
FORTRAN output 0
FORTRAN output 1
FORTRAN output 2
FORTRAN output 3
FORTRAN output 4
FORTRAN output 5
FORTRAN output 6
FORTRAN output 7
FORTRAN output 8
FORTRAN output 9
```

If this doesn't do quite what you want, you could have a look at the "send_tty" command inside "expect" to send an extra copy of program inputs to the terminal - maybe.

Comment: Thank you again for your response Mark. I understand what you are getting at and this may work. Unfortunately the FORTRAN programs are fairly long and complex and have many different prompts for many different cases. Therefor to program an expect script would be much more complex than to patch the FORTRAN program to echo each input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 6<&0
exec 6>stdin.log

echo -e "Responses\nTo\nFORTRAN\nPrompts" > myprogram.in
tee file.log < myprogram.in | ./myprogram >> file.log
```

In stdin.log you should have a log of your inputs and of your program...

Comment: Thank you for your response, but unfortunately this also does not work. As the first line `exec 6<&0` sets file descriptor 6 to the shell terminal window `dev/tty`. Then immediately changes the file descriptor 6 to stdin.log `exec 6>stdin.log`. After running stdin.log is just an empty file.